# If just for a website, phonegap or native app?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm a web designer.

I have a site like to a forum.

so I want to create a app for my user.

The app just show and insert my website date(mysql).

**normal function**

1. member login
2. member reg
3. post topic
4. reply topic
5. search topic
6. a message box function  (user send user)
7. admin user will delete topic

**maybe function**

maybe I need mobile phone push message function, maybe user's topic anyone reply

I know phonegap has **PushPlugin**

that plugin can do that?

.

My skill just php,mysql,html,css, a little js

I can create function 1-7 in mobile version website. But I don't know how to make to a apps.

These are my case

You have any suggestions?

I should learn native app or phonegap?

if native I need learn ios and and android, I need ios version and android version

Comment: We are not here to recommend for/against any particular package or programming method. We are also not here to tell you how you should build your system.

Comment: I understand your dilemma, I really do, but this is not the right forum for this question. It is likely to be closed. No one can really answer this question for you sufficiently. Native languages are surely going to more powerful and better at building native apps. Do you need to learn them? Can you get away with just using phonegap? Maybe. Who knows. Do some research. "Should I learn native or phonegap?" Pick one. Start there. Then learn the other.

Comment: This question is better placed here: [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap can do the trick for the mobile app.
But since you're new to apps development, keep this piece of advice in your mind.
Data storage based apps never use direct storage on mysql, a hacker can revert your code and extract your database password and you're done for that.
always think of using API for reading data and Authentications like oAuth2 for insertions.
Good luck !